# Error while value showing in textview

Tags: android, textview, settext

I am stuck in some problem and i search alot but did not find any solution here is my code

```
   private void rotateDialer(float degrees, int angleMove) {
    angleMove = conversionAngles(angleMove);
    // txt.setText(""+angleMove);
    // matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight / 2);
    // dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    if (angleMove < 36 && angleMove >= 0) {
        settingMinutesNeedle(36);
        // /addAngles = addAngles + 36;
    } else if (angleMove >= 36 && angleMove < 72)
        settingMinutesNeedle(72);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 2) && angleMove < (36 * 3)) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "move angle "+angleMove,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//error here         tvval.setText(angleMove);




settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 3);
    } else if (angleMove >= (36 * 3) && angleMove < (36 * 4))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 4);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 4) && angleMove < (36 * 5))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 5);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 5) && angleMove < (36 * 6))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 6);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 6) && angleMove < (36 * 7))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 7);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 7) && angleMove < (36 * 8))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 8);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 8) && angleMove < (36 * 9))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 9);
    else if (angleMove >= (36 * 9) && angleMove < (36 * 10))
        settingMinutesNeedle(36 * 10);
    // count = count + 1;
}
```

when i toast value it do not give any error but when i set it in textview it shows "Exception dispatching input event"

How i can resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 tvval.setText(String.valueOf(angleMove));
```

`angleMove` is int. `setText` has methods one that takes int which looks for resource with the id mentioned if not found you get `ResourceNotFoundException` and the other than takes `CharacterSequence`. So you need to use `String.valueOf(angleMove)`

Answer (score 2):

like you did above, do

```
tvval.setText(""+angleMove);
```

because you can't directly set an int or float value to your textview

Comment: You're correct regarding `float`, but you CAN use `int` value. New user just doesn't expect the behavior when using `int`. (as already explained in other answer)

Answer (score 2):

Just try below code:

```
tvval.setText(String.valueOf(angleMove));
```

I think this will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

`angleMove` is `int`, abd `TextView.setText()` expects a `CharSequence...`

**So, You can do as following:**

```
tvval.setText(angleMove + "");
```

Comment: Partly true, partly false. `setText()` also allows `int`, but it will find a string resource instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tvval.setText(angleMove + "");
```